# Sharing things in facebook using fb_graph gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, access-token, sharing, fb-graph

I'm trying to share in facebook while creating the content using fb_graph(2.6.0) gem,

i'm getting following errors while trying  :

```
app = FbGraph::Application.new(APP_ID, :secret => APP_SECRET)
app.get_access_token
user = FbGraph::User.me(access_token).fetch
```

In Development console

```
 => 377095675642525|X3SyfucEUnahEEFAFwkO_cFXRyc 
 1.9.3p194 :005 > user = FbGraph::User.me(access_token).fetch
 LoadError: cannot load such file -- {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
from /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
from /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
from /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
from /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
from /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
from /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/fb_graph-2.6.0/lib/fb_graph/node.rb:138:in `handle_response'
from /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/fb_graph-2.6.0/lib/fb_graph/node.rb:49:in `get'
from /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/fb_graph-2.6.0/lib/fb_graph/node.rb:19:in `fetch'
from (irb):5
from /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
from /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

In Heroku logs :

```
 Started GET "/facebook/callback?code=AQDccVXzo55GpSCCnr0vXKb2xpHFtJ8E_Eb-3AfA6Wcx5G1QEMHr4vNuH0366tGYVFepTuDZv2Z9_BLeXdMRNcLtfg1N3mz8rbTZowblEeGqg9Ls7R7X7P2GiuyFPJa0PTric7gjE8cZ3olRyP27otiGfzWQ4REoqS-BFsH4BwyfyZSiZxoQ0PPDUmlxeve4Cn9qAKzC2sYmEEbdTcPo2quu" for 122.164.241.1 at 2013-02-26 05:42:55 +0000
2013-02-26T05:42:56+00:00 app[web.1]: #<FbGraph::Auth:0x00000004e1bbb8 @client=#   <Rack::OAuth2::Client:0x00000004e19b38 @identifier=188451457933295, @secret="13d6158a6ebe35a115bcae7f0ec14826", @redirect_uri=nil, @scheme=nil, @host="graph.facebook.com", @port=nil, @authorization_endpoint="/oauth/authorize", @token_endpoint="/oauth/access_token", @grant=#  <Rack::OAuth2::Client::Grant::ClientCredentials:0x00000005484e28>>>
app/controllers/facebooks_controller.rb:29:in `create'
2013-02-26T05:42:56+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/facebook/callback?code=AQDccVXzo55GpSCCnr0vXKb2xpHFtJ8E_Eb-3AfA6Wcx5G1QEMHr4vNuH0366tGYVFepTuDZv2Z9_BLeXdMRNcLtfg1N3mz8rbTZowblEeGqg9Ls7R7X7P2GiuyFPJa0PTric7gjE8cZ3olRyP27otiGfzWQ4REoqS-BFsH4BwyfyZSiZxoQ0PPDUmlxeve4Cn9qAKzC2sYmEEbdTcPo2quu host=x.y.com fwd="122.164.241.1" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=431ms status=500 bytes=0
```

After clicking login in facebook i'm getting following error in browser,

```
Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving     http://x.y.com/facebook/callback?code=AQAGIeV8GLZWMI98eauog2eTDq7jeXBEhBSDg3izqBBjS6mVN3y5tgTSGcagmAqMTYHyB_EJArN834cglLjBL4yHDQHlEaD7j7wSmSPN43hZXQhCHJTbvP0HHJPBwAiNCCZYOiP2jpLLAyznLoufwvN-6p6dLgjup8WPtRyEeUspv94m-O5lC146JHNvWFUvCHaPaQ2wPWyfmh5C89mR2G0R#_=_. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
```

Comment: when you say 'share', what you want to share ? Do you want to post on the users wall ?
You might also need [extended-permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/) for doing so

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems you are using applications access token to access user info. That reslts in

```
FbGraph::InvalidRequest: OAuthException :: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

Whereas you should be using user's access token to fetch the profile info or post on your wall.

In case you are trying to do omniauth login with Facebook, here's a nice tutorial to get started http://blog.yangtheman.com/2012/02/09/facebook-connect-with-rails-omniauth-devise/

When using [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) You should be have user's access token to carry out any further actions for example to Update status (wall post)

This requires an access token, which you should be saving while authenticating you app for that user.

**You can do**

```
me = FbGraph::User.me(ACCESS_TOKEN)
me.feed!(
  :message => 'Updating via FbGraph',
  :picture => 'https://graph.facebook.com/matake/picture',
  :link => 'https://github.com/nov/fb_graph',
  :name => 'FbGraph',
  :description => 'A Ruby wrapper for Facebook Graph API'
)
```

Note: This would require extended permissions which you can specify in scope attribute

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  # The following is for facebook
  provider :facebook, [APP ID], [SECRET KEY], {:scope =&gt; 'email, read_stream, read_friendlists, friends_likes, friends_status, offline_access'}

  # If you want to also configure for additional login services, they would be configured here.
end
```

Comment: So where do I get the ACCESS_TOKEN from? I thought like the OP that `app.get_access_token` will give it to me but you're saying that this is a different access token then the one User.me() expects. I am also using fb_graph.

Comment: You need to authenticate the user to get ones access token called as Facebook OAuth flow try out https://github.com/nov/fb_graph#authentication or https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook (later one would be easy to setup and use)